# Routing error shows missing one argument?

Tags: flutter, constructor, routes

This is how i am routing to next page ,

```
   '/ot1': (context) => CustomListView(),
```

and it was working fine onTAP

```
onTap: (){
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/ot1');
                },
```

but when i created constructor in `class CustomListView` and passed field i got this error that one argument is missing in this line  `'/ot1': (context) => CustomListView(),`

this is the code of my `class CustomListView` share below

```
class CustomListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Spacecraft> spacecrafts;
  CustomListView(this.spacecrafts);

  Widget build(context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: spacecrafts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex) {
        return createViewItem(spacecrafts[currentIndex], context);
      },
    );
  }
```

I have searched for it for so much and didn't find a solution new to programming and FLUTTER language please HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding square brackets [this.spacecrafts] so that the spacecraft argument becomes an optional argument.

```
class CustomListView extends StatelessWidget {
final List<Spacecraft> spacecrafts;
CustomListView([this.spacecrafts]); # <- this is where you use the brackets
...
```

Comment: return new CustomListView({spacecrafts}); now its giving error on this line .. why is that so ? error: Too many positional arguments 0 expected but found 1

Comment: @RAJASAHAB Answer is updated. only change that part I pointed to

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass data between screen using pushedName do it like,

```
 Navigator.pushNamed(
              context, '/ot1', arguments: mFeedData);
```

and fetch data like,

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    mFeedData = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    ....
  }
```

**if you do not wish to pass any data then remove below portion from your code**

```
CustomListView(this.spacecrafts)
```

**or make it as an  optional positional argument,**

```
CustomListView([this.spacecrafts])
```

**What is [Positional parameter?](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters)**

> Wrapping a set of function parameters in [] marks them as optional positional parameters:

**What is [Named parameters?](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters)**

> When calling a function, you can specify named parameters using *paramName: value*. 
>   For example:

`enableFlags(bold: true, hidden: false);`

When defining a function, use `{param1, param2, …}` to specify named parameters:

```
/// Sets the [bold] and [hidden] flags ...
void enableFlags({bool bold, bool hidden}) {...}
```

Comment: i am not passing any data

Comment: The problem is that your CustomListView class have a constructor `CustomListView(this.spacecrafts);
` which accepts a list `spacecrafts` as an argument, and from pushedName, you are not passing any argument. So if you do not wish to pass any list then remove the constructor.

Comment: return new CustomListView({spacecrafts}); now its giving error on this line .. why is that so ? error: Too many positional arguments 0 expected but found 1

Comment: do not enclose with curly braces {}, use square brackets [] for making it optional. See in my answer.

Comment: wow .. can i have tution classes from you ? Nice loved it ....

Answer (score 0):

I am using this solution for navigation in my Flutter apps:

```
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    // Getting arguments passed in while calling Navigator.pushNamed
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Home());

      case '/routeWithoutArguments':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => PageWithoutArguments(),
        );

      case '/routeWithArguments':
        if (args is String) { // I check if the arguments provided are valids
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => PageWithArguments(myString: args),
          );
        }
        return _errorRoute();

      default:
        return _errorRoute();
    }
  }

  static Route<dynamic> _errorRoute() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Error'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('ERROR'),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Then in my widget `App`:

```
MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: '/',
    onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
    ...
)
```

Then to call my routes without arguments:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
    context,
    '/routeWithoutArguments',
);
```

and to call with arguments:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
    context,
    '/routeWithArguments',
    arguments: "my argument",
);
```

I have learn this solution from [ResoCoder](https://resocoder.com/2019/04/27/flutter-routes-navigation-parameters-named-routes-ongenerateroute/)